# SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3. IE 10 jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, multipartform-data

I got an error like

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.

I used multipart form data to upload a large file size. Its works all the browsers except IE10. This is my piece of code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "FileService.svc/UploadedFile",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {}
})
```

Can anyone give a solution to fix this issue. Im struck up with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

LINKED ANSWER FROM [OTHER QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145688/ie10-11-ajax-xhr-error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3)

I had this problem with an IIS application, an AJAX Post request that returned some JSON would fail, eventually returning abort, with the:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3 error in the console.

On other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) the exact same AJAX
request was fine.

Further investigation revealed that the response from the server was missing the status code - in this case it should have been 500 internal error.

This was being generated as part of a C# web application using service stack that requires an error code to be explicitly set.

IE seemed to leave the connection open, eventually the network layer closed it and it 'aborted' the request; despite receiving the content and other headers.

Updating the web application to correctly return the status code fixed the issue.

Perhaps there is an issue with how IE is handling the headers in posts.

Hope this helps someone!