# Azure website IE10/11 error SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, azure, signalr

We are experiencing this error in IE10/11 and have spent the last 2 days researching about it and have not been able to find a solution. We are running a asp.net mvc 5 web application utilizing signalR in specific areas hosted on a azure website that is scaled up to 2 instances. We are using the Redis backplane mod to make sure our SignalR talks back to all instances of the application. The error is intermittent and causes the rest of the application to hang. We do not believe this is a SignalR issue because we removed the invocation of SignalR from the page and was still able to get the issue to occur.

We have tried the following

1. GET request before POST
2. Setting the charset=utf-8
3. Our JS libraries are update to date

We need to find a fix for this issue quickly so if anyone has any ideas I would be really greatful.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One problem when scaling a SignalR application on more instances is that clients  connected to a server only receive updates from other clients from  the same server. (The messages are not automatically broadcast between all servers).

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

One solution is to have a backplane that automatically sends the messages between servers, so  that any server has any message at any time so it can push updates to their connected interested clients.

There are two implementations that Microsoft explains in the link above, one using Redis Pub/Sub and the other using Azure Service Bus.

With Redis you simply get an instance running (it can be on Linux, Windows or in Azure) and configure each server to push messages and subscribe to messages on the same channel.

I hope it helps your problem (since you said that the problem is intermitent, I can assume that it appears when clients are connected to different instances of your application).

Good luck!

EDIT:

Thanks for updating your question.

Have a look at this SO post:
[IE10/11 Ajax XHR error - SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145688/ie10-11-ajax-xhr-error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3)

And at this post:
http://www.kewlcodes.com/posts/5/SCRIPT7002-XMLHttpRequest-Network-Error-0x2ef3-Could-not-complete-the-operation-due-to-error-00002ef3

Good luck!

Comment: Yes. I am already using the Redis backplane so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: And where in the question have you stated this?

Comment: And how would I have known it? If you are not giving us the details  of the problem,  we cannot help! I suggest you edit your question!

Comment: Sorry, I edited by question. Still new at asking questions on here. thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue. In my case, I used IOwinContext.Request.ReadFormAsync() in my server code. I found out that if I send a post request with json content type, ReadFormAsync() hangs.
I solved it by checking if the request's content type is json, and if so, I use a different method to parse the body.