# CORS request aborted when adding a custom header in AJAX CORS request in IE10

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-headers, cors

When I add this header to my jQueryAjax request:

```
headers: {
    "Authorization": "SomeValue"
}
```

on the server I add the Authorization header to the

```
h.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Authorization");
```

This works fine in other browsers but not in IE10!

[image: Options Preflight request]

ONE REMARK:

If I comment out the authentication header, refresh the page, issue a regular GET request to my web api which by default does not trigger a preflight request.
After that request, I uncomment the custom header in my jquery request, save, refresh the page, issue a new request with a custom header, which then executes successfully !

In IE 10 web developer tools I can see an error message:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied
>
> SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for
>   https://mywebapi.dev/api/authentication/cors/ required Cross Origin
>   Resource Sharing (CORS).  cors SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for
>   https://mywebapi.dev/api/authentication/cors/ required CORS preflight.
>   cors SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is
>   denied.

The request is aborted right away, it never reaches the message handler!

Comment: I have the same problem, IE10 just ignores `Authorization` header. Is there any solution?

Comment: You have to provide more information. The authorization header is not sent during an Options request by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23252866/2581562) and explained by @EricLaw in the anser/comment section. I found it now, because I googled the error code

> SCRIPT7002

**What I have done is:**

1. I went to IIS where my webapi is hosted and
2. Click/mark my web application which is hosting my webapi and
3. Go to SSL Settings-> Check Ignore Client Certificates!.

Now the the preflight CORS request goes through using IE10.