# Angular and IE11 XmlHttpRequest issue, looking for work around or real solution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, strophe.js

I used strophe.js for implementing the IM Chat app with Angular JS, and everything work fine in another browser, chrome, firefox, Opera, and Safari, but there are some issue with IE11 and MS Edge Browser that 
cause the chat to not working at all. When I go to check the log in the console here is what i get and also another error log XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3:

[image]

Comment: Are you using JSON by any chance to pass data around?

Comment: yes we parse it from text/xml to json format for passing the data around which happening in the xmpp client and xmpp muc

Comment: I think the solution to your problem is in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145688/ie10-11-ajax-xhr-error-script7002-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ef3/32106649#32106649

Comment: let me check first and i will come back to you

Comment: @MeilyChhon I work on the Microsoft Edge team, and would love to know if you're still running into this issue.

Comment: Hello @Sampson, yes we are still working on it and it seem that problem doesn't go away, i search through the microsoft forum too. If I make progress on the issue, i will contact you directly on twitter. Ehh Thanks you so much for coming to comment here. I am glad that I got support directly from MS Edge Team. :D

Comment: @MeilyChhon Is the page online? Can I access the document?

Comment: Man how Microsoft has changed. They are now proactively trying to help their users. Hopefully this team won't be an exception.

Comment: @Sampson i have sent you a direct message on twitter. I hope u received it. and yeah the problem with the CORS preflight seem to not go away but however, i have found out the reason why our chat application is not operating quite well on IE, the reason is because of the framework, strophe.js that we use seem to ignore IE way of dealing with the xml data that we fetch from xmpp.

Comment: @MeilyChhon I'll check my DMs. In the meantime, if you happen to open any other questions here regarding IE and Strophe, I'd be happy to assist in any way possible. While we aren't likely to do any feature-related work on IE, I can try to help find alternative routes around its shortcomings.