# Why is my XMLHttpRequest being aborted?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, authentication, xmlhttprequest

I have an XMLHttpRequest that I'm sending to log in to a remote server. I'm taking the login parameters (username and password) and sending them as json. Here's my code:

```
var json_data = JSON.stringify({
    "method": "login",
    "user_login": user,
    "password": password
});

var post_url = "server_url";


var crossRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
crossRequest.open('POST', post_url, true);    //Async
crossRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
crossRequest.withCredentials = true;

crossRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (crossRequest.readyState == 4) {

        alert("Logged in!");
    }
}


crossRequest.onabort = function () {
    alert("ERROR: Aborted.");
}

crossRequest.onerror = function () {
    //alert("Error occurred, status: " + crossRequest.status);
}

crossRequest.onload = function () {
    if (crossRequest.status == 200)
    {
        alert("Logged in!");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("An error occurred, status: " + crossRequest.status);
    }
}

crossRequest.send(json_data);
```

It works just fine in Chrome, but in IE 11 it always aborts, seemingly before sending anything:

[image: IE 11 Dev Panel Network]

[image: IE 11 Dev Panel Error]

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like existing IE11 issue

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/877525/ie11-returns-status-0-during-ajax-post-operation-from-an-iframe-xmlhttprequest-network-error-0x2ee4#tabs

[IE10/IE11 Abort Post Ajax Request After Clearing Cache with error "Network Error 0x2ef3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312938/ie10-ie11-abort-post-ajax-request-after-clearing-cache-with-error-network-error)

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/852785/ie10-network-error-0x2ee4-https-proxy-ajax

Answer (score 0):

• Press Alt, then go to Tools and turn off Enterprise mode if it’s not turned off yet.
• Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Reset all zones to default level
• Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Restore advanced settings
• Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> General -> Delete -> Temporary Internet Files and website files.